# How do I access attributes from within a block?

Tags: views, blocks

So I'm calling a block within a HTML container in Drupal 7.x with a shortcode. There is an option for a Dynamic Shortcode as well but alas there is no documentation in the code base.

```
[block admin_url = "admin/structure/block/manage/block/244" hello="World" ][/block]
```

This pulls the Block to the page and I can see output from PHP within its content.

However! I was wondering from within the block if there is any way to access the attribute "hello"  Or if this is impossible?

---

Basically I'm trying to create a single block which can take a parameter for a tag name that calls a View and displays the top 3 blogs from that tag.  It's all so easy, until you try to do it in Drupal 7.x.

The only other solution I can think of is to create a Block for all 20 tags which then call the same view to retrieve the 3 blog posts.